# Pronoun after verb "to be"

Tags: pronouns, copular-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who wants ice-cream?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/who-wants-ice-cream)
>   [Which is correct to say: “It's me” or “It's I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i)
>   [“This is her” or “This is she”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/this-is-her-or-this-is-she)

I'm reading a book and I found a sentence which made me have some doubts.

The sentence is:

> That was **him** on the phone.

I wonder whether the sentence would be as grammatically correct as 'That was **he** on the phone'. The reason I wonder is because when you answer the phone, for example, you say "yes, this is he" (meaning something like 'Speaking').

So are both grammatically correct? How can I know whether I should use *he/him* after verb *to be*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/it-is-they-who-lied-or-it-is-them-who-lied http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/this-is-her-or-this-is-she and a couple of others

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. None of questions indicated as duplicate really addresses this one. In "who wants ice cream?" there's no **to be** involved. "This is her" is about answering the phone. Finally, "Which is correct to say: It's me or It's I" is about the first person in particular, whereas this question is general.