# "It is fun to be him/he." Which is correct?

Tags: infinitives, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, be, copular-verbs

Would you use *him* or *he* in the following sentence?

> It is fun to be **him/he**.

A teacher told me that you use the object form after the infinitive of *to be.* Is this true?

I am a native English speaker, but I am trying to figure out what the SAT wants me to think people should speak like.

Comment: Traditionally, *he* would be used.  In most modern contexts, however, *him* is far more common.

Comment: but, grammatically speaking, why did my teacher say that him is correct? I asked about the grammar, and mentioned that to be always takes the subject case, but he still said it is him. @Anonym

Comment: In modern English, any non-possessive personal pronoun that is the object of a verb, or of a preposition, or comes after a verb, is objective (_me, you, him, her, it, us, them_). Anything else is a joke, or non-native speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is not true though... You would say it is I and not it is me.

Comment: I would say "It's me". "It is I" is, as I said, a joke.

Comment: Excuse me?  I don't think I understand... @JohnLawler

Comment: Deinde ego te absolvo a peccatis tuis. As I said, native English speakers do not say "It is I", at least not without a grin. We say, when we need to, "It's me". Which isn't very often, after all, because the sentence means nothing at all (who else could it be?) and only serves to allow the listener to recognize the voice.

Comment: @JohnLawler Don't know Latin.

Comment: It means you're excused.

Comment: @JohnLawler I am a native English speaker, but I am trying to figure out what the SAT wants me to think people should speak like.

Comment: Can't help you there, sorry. Those things are not made up to test your knowledge of English but rather your skill in taking tests. Good luck. But I doubt that kind of stuff will be on the exam, and _fun to be him/her/me/us/them_ is in fact the correct form. The rule I mentioned above is the actual rule.

Comment: You are trying to reconcile 60-year-old rules of English ('It is I') with modern rules ('It's me'). Or put them in a sentimental rank order. It doesn't work. Sadly, some teachers haven't realised that the rules have changed – yes, largely to reflect how most people actually speak. And some of them believe that the ones they were shackled to had divine authority and pre-date England.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Trying to say *I am him* and *I become him* are correct is trying to say that *be* and *become* take objects. I'd like to see someone try to prove that.

Comment: @Edna Mode No; it's accepting that English 'rules' are not set in tablets of stone. [One of the most respected and famous linguists of recent times says that the 'It is I' brigade are trying to resurrect the dead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143363/that-was-me-vs-that-was-i/143365#143365). And I seem to remember reading that 'It is I' was actually an arrogation to echo Latin constructions, forcibly  introduced centuries ago, at a time when the use of the accusative case was the norm with complements as well as with DOs. Would you have objected to _that_ breaking of the 'rules'?

Comment: ... [Hans Adler, in this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/which-is-correct-this-is-her-or-this-is-she), has a lot to say about the way the language has in past centuries often been mishandled by the minority who could actually write, and how misunderstandings were often put into print and perpetuated.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true.

The general rule of thumb is: if there is any ambiguity, use *me / her / him*.

There are some special-case exceptions to this rule in traditional, formal English – e.g. *It is I!*, rather than *It's me!* – but *It is fun to be him.* is not one of them.

Comment: It is fun to be *he*.