# In a specific construction of the sentence below, which one should be use: he or him?

Tags: objective-case

In a college exam reviewer, I encountered a sentence:

**I suspect the murderer to be him.**

I am confused about whether or not the objective *him* is the appropriate case to use there when it appears to be a subject complement (since it comes after the linking verb *be*. Shouldn't it be

**I suspect the murderer to be he.**?

I tried browsing the internet but failed to find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In search of a Grammar text, of any vintage, that covers such as the below](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/482754/in-search-of-a-grammar-text-of-any-vintage-that-covers-such-as-the-below). The traditional rule is to use "him" in this kind of sentence to match the (allegedly accusative, although invisible) case of "the murderer".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97038/discussion-on-question-by-alejandro-in-a-specific-construction-of-the-sentence-b).

Answer (score 0):

They both sound awkward to me. I'd personally rearrange it to

'I suspect he is the murderer'

or

'I suspect him to be the murderer'

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97039/discussion-on-answer-by-fifthviolet-in-a-specific-construction-of-the-sentence-b).