# As to grammar and idiom, is the following extract correct: “… if you know the man or are him, call …”?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Obviously, my questions refers to the pronoun him. Am I wrong to suppose that the use of the subject case pronoun he instead of him would not improve the previous statement? What about this one: “… if you know the man or are the man, call …”? Can you come up with a natural sounding wording?

Comment: You cannot be he. You can only be him.

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/which-is-correct-this-is-her-or-this-is-she

Comment: _If you know or are this man..._

Comment: *if you know the identity of this person* should cover it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: "Sometimes, there's a man, well, he's the man for his time and place. He fits right in there."

Comment: Why use deletions and pronoun at all? _If you know this man, or if you are this man, ..._

Comment: What's wrong with it the way it is??

Comment: Could the man be a woman? Could a person be the one? Could the one be two?

Comment: This sounds subjective but a more _natural_ sounding alternative may be: `if you are the man (in question) or know him, call …`

Comment: You are not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

> “… if you know the man or are him, call …”

can be separated out into two separate phrases:

> “… if you know the man, call …”
>
> “… if you are him, call …”?

both of which are grammatically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could say "If you or someone you know is the man..."

Comment: People don't like that because the verb cannot agree with both subjects ("If you ... is the man").

Comment: True, but isn't it more concise then using both 'man' and 'him'?.              I ran a search and it seems to be commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an alternate sentence,

> If you are the man, or [you] know him, please call ...

which is grammatically (and importantly, also naturally) correct.

Otherwise,

> If you know the man, or you are him, please call ...

is only a three-letter word more, but also sounds natural and allows the order of concepts in the original phrasing to be kept.